# WooCommerce custom checkout page redirection for specific product categories

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, checkout

If you buy a product from product category "Special" you should be redirected from /checkout/ to /newcheckout/.

When I run this code, nothing is redirect/happens so I am not sure where the fault is:

```
/*
 * Redirect payment gateway based on category.
 */
function ace_disable_payment_gateway_category( $gateways ) {
    // Categories that'll redorect the payment gateway 
    $category_slugs = array( 'special');
    $category_ids = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'slug' => $category_slugs, 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
    $url = '/newcheckout/'; // New checkout URL

    // Check each cart item for given category
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        $product = $item['data'];
if (is_page('checkout') {
        if ( $product && array_intersect( $category_ids, $product->get_category_ids() ) ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( $url ) // Redirect to newcheckout
            break;
        }
    }
}
    return $gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'ace_disable_payment_gateway_category' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The best hook for redirections is `template_redirect` action hook. Note that filters hooks are note made for redirection. So your code should be:

```
// Custom checkout page for specific product categories.
add_filter( 'template_redirect', 'product_category_checkout_redirection' );
function product_category_checkout_redirection() {
    // Only on checkout page
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :

    // Categories that redirects
    $product_categories = array( 'special'); // Product categories (can be a term Id, slug or name)
    $new_checkout_url   = home_url('/newcheckout/'); // New checkout URL

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( has_term( $product_categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( $new_checkout_url ); // Redirects to "newcheckout"
            exit();
        }
    }

    endif;
}
```

Code goes on functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.